# What happens to flow rules when OVS loses connection to a controller?

Tags: openflow, openvswitch

In my understanding, the flow rules stay present. My issue is with rules that direct the packet to the controller. If a new flow comes in, for example, and the controller is down, will this new packet simply be dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will this new packet simply be dropped?

Exactly!

Comment: Is there a way to "disable" rules which have an action to be "sent to the controller", so it can instead match on the next largest matching rule?

Answer (score 0):

Its up to the configuration whether the flows will present or not. Here is the explanation from [Openflow 1.3 documentation](https://3vf60mmveq1g8vzn48q2o71a-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-spec-v1.3.0.pdf):

> Flow entries are removed from flow tables in two ways, either at the
>   request of the controller or via the switch flow expiry mechanism. The
>   switch flow expiry mechanism that is run by the switch independantly
>   of the controller and is based on the state and configuration of  flow
>   entries. Each flow entry has an idle_timeout and a hard_timeout
>   associated with it. If either value is non-zero, the switch must note
>   the flow entry's arrival time, as it may need to evict the entry
>   later. A non-zero hard_timeout field causes the flow entry to be
>   removed after the given number of seconds, regardless of how many
>   packets it has matched. A non-zero idle_timeout field causes the flow
>   entry to be removed when it has matched no packets in the given number
>   of seconds. The switch must implement flow expiry and remove flow
>   entries from the flow table when one of their timeout is exceeded.

If both idle_timeout and hard_timeout are zero, the entry is considered permanent and will never time out:

> If the idle_timeout is set and the hard_timeout is zero, the entry
>   must expire after idle_timeout seconds with no received trafic. If the
>   idle_timeout is zero and the hard_timeout is set, the entry must
>   expire in hard_timeout seconds regardless of whether or not packets
>   are hitting the entry. If both idle_timeout and hard_timeout are set,
>   the  flow entry will timeout after idle_timeout seconds with no
>   trafic, or hard_timeout seconds, whichever comes first. If both
>   idle_timeout and hard_timeout are zero, the entry is considered
>   permanent and will never time out. It can still be removed with a
>   flow_mod message of type OFPFC_DELETE.